# How to select latest rank of item in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables: `coins` and `coin_history`

`coins` table

```
|id | symbol | date     | 
+---+--------+----------+
|1  |  BTC   |01-02-2011|
|2  |  ETH   |21-02-2011|
|3  |  XRP   |08-01-2011|
|4  |  BCH   |25-01-2011|
```

`coin_history` table; rank of each coin on a date

```
|id | coin_id | rank   | date     | 
+---+---------+--------+----------+
| 1 |    1    |   1    |01-02-2018|
| 2 |    1    |   1    |02-02-2018|
| 3 |    1    |   1    |04-02-2018|
| 4 |    2    |   2    |01-02-2018|
| 5 |    2    |   3    |02-02-2018|
| 6 |    2    |   2    |04-02-2018|
| 7 |    3    |   3    |01-02-2018|
| 8 |    3    |   2    |02-02-2018|
| 9 |    3    |   4    |04-02-2018|
|10 |    4    |   4    |01-02-2018|
|11 |    4    |   4    |02-02-2018|
|12 |    4    |   3    |04-02-2018|
```

I want to get each coin from `coins` ordered by latest rank from `coin_history`

something link this result:

```
|coin_id | symbol |  rank  |
+--------+--------+--------+
|   1    |  BTC   |   1    |
|   2    |  ETH   |   2    |
|   4    |  BCH   |   3    |
|   3    |  XRP   |   4    |
```

I've tried some queries but all of them result to this error

> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), get the Maximum value of date from the history for a particular coin.
- Join this result-set with your main tables, to fetch only the row corresponding to recent date for a coin.
- Eventually, use `ORDER BY` to get result in Ascending order for Rank.

Try:

```
SELECT 
  c.coin_id, 
  c.symbol, 
  ch.rank 
FROM 
  coins AS c 
JOIN 
  coin_history AS ch 
    ON ch.coin_id = c.coin_id 
JOIN 
  (
   SELECT coin_id, 
          MAX(date) AS max_date 
   FROM coin_history 
   GROUP BY coin_id 
  ) AS dt 
    ON ch.coin_id = dt.coin_id AND 
       ch.date = dt.max_date
ORDER BY ch.rank
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `SELECT coin_id, 
          MAX(date) AS max_date 
   FROM coin_history` be `SELECT coin_id, 
          MAX(date) AS max_date 
   FROM coin_history GROUP BY coin_id`

Comment: @Hadu use the updated answer please. there was a code typo

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a other more simple method but it is MySQL only, so don't use this when you need database portability in your code.

Using GROUP_CONCAT in combination with nested SUBSTRING_INDEX functions to get the first element/item can also be used to get a extra column which keeping the correct grouped information..

Note: `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` is very important to use otherwise GROUP_CONCAT will only display 1024 bytes..

**Query**

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;

SELECT 
   coins.id AS coin_id
 , coins.symbol
 , CAST( 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           GROUP_CONCAT(coin_history.rank ORDER BY coin_history.date DESC)
         , ','
         , 1
        )
        , ','
       , -1
   ) AS UNSIGNED) AS rank
FROM 
 coins
INNER JOIN
 coin_history
ON
 coins.id = coin_history.coin_id

GROUP BY 
   coins.id
 , coins.symbol

ORDER BY 
 rank
```

**Result**

```
| coin_id | symbol | rank |
| ------- | ------ | ---- |
| 1       | BTC    | 1    |
| 2       | ETH    | 2    |
| 4       | BCH    | 3    |
| 3       | XRP    | 4    |
```

[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9bLb8j6k3PEfGpcQAg4aa/1)

Comment: Can't show you the result here in comments section, but the rank is considered as string and sort is not correct

Comment: @Hadu mine result is the same as your expected result in the question.

Comment: Because all ranks in the question are one digit numbers, if you have a two digit rank number, string sort will give you the wrong result

Comment: "if you have a two digit rank number, string sort will give you the wrong result " Yes that indeed will happen.. i didn't catch on what you meant the first comment @Hadu you can covert the string into a int with a CAST.. see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9bLb8j6k3PEfGpcQAg4aa/1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT q.*from
  (SELECT h.*, c.symbol
   FROM `coin_history` AS h
   JOIN coins AS c ON h.coin_id = c.id
   ORDER BY h.date DESC
   LIMIT 50) AS q
GROUP BY q.coin_id
ORDER BY q.rank ASC
```

Comment: `[42000][1055] Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'q.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`